# Bootstrap 2.3 typeahead is going behind of another view (coming from knockout view binding)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, typeahead.js

**I tried solving this with `z-index`, but it's not working. Please do not suggest `z-index` solutions.**

I am using Knockout in my web page built with Typescript. I have three different pages. I am binding all those into one page using Knockout. In the First division I am using Bootstrap TypeAhead, this is displaying properly on top of second division. But in the Third division I developed Flip actions for this I used so many absolutes in Third division. Due to this my Typeahead is going behind on third division. I checked with all `z-index` properties, but still couldn't get it to work.

Is there any way to fix that?

I tried for code, but all is built with Typescript.

```
<div data-bind="compose: { model: filterList, view: 'Prospect/FiltersList' }"></div>
<div id="divCustomerList" data-bind="compose: { model: customerList, view: 'Prospect/CustomerList' }"></div>
<div id="div4" data-bind="compose: { model: leadslistViewModel, view: 'Prospect/LeadsList' }"></div>
```

In the first "FilterList" I am using knockout-bootstrap-typeahead.

In the third "LeadList" I am using CSS flip functionality.

The flip functionality and CSS in third division is same as [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/2vkojdh3/),

**TypeaHead CSS** has:

```
.filterpage + ul.typeahead.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 3px 2px !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}

.dropdown-menu{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1051;
}
```

Please see the image below:

[image: example rendering]

Comment: Please include the CSS you are using.

Comment: @RoyJ: Sorry for late. For this I have lot of code. So, I just included sample fiddle(Same I am using in my project) for third division. and included type ahead control css.